# Detecting if javascript is executing in a frame

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, frames

In Firefox if I use `frames[i].document.readyState` it will say complete even though the frame is executing Javascript.

Is there a way to detect if Javascript is executing in a frame?

Comment: Do you mean you want to see if the frame is busy running JavaScript (from outside the frame), or you want to write JavaScript code that checks whether it's running in a frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frames run on the same thread as their owner.  You can verify this by having a child frame run a long loop whilst the parent has some code executing on a short timer — you'll notice that the parent's timer has to wait until the loop ends before it can execute its callback.

This means that a child frame and its parent cannot execute scripts simultaneously.  Your check isn't running until the JavaScript in the child frame has finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var in_iframe = window != window.top;
```